How can I incrementally increase a displayed array element using a rails button?
I have two arrays @necklines and @skirts, made up of all Neckline models, and Skirt models respectively.
I am attempting to show one neckline and one skirt at a time, and having two buttons to either incrementally increase or decrease the current displayed element.
page layout as follows:
I am attempting to do this by calling on @necklines[@ni] and @skirts[@si], and using the buttons to either increase or decrease the value of @ni and @si.
However, when I click on any of the buttons the element doesn't change.
Here is my MainController.rb
    def home
        @necklines = Neckline.all
        @skirts = Skirt.all
        
        if @ni.nil?
            @ni = 0
        end

        if @si.nil?
            @si = 0
        end

    end

    def increase_neck
        if @ni >= @necklines.count - 1
            @ni = 0
        else
            @ni += 1
        end
        redirect_to root_path    
    end

    def decrease_neck
        if @ni <= 0
            @ni = @necklines.count - 1
        else
            @ni -= 1
        end
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    def increase_skirt
        if @si >= @skirts.count - 1
            @si = 0
        else
            @si += 1
        end 
        redirect_to root_path   
    end

    def decrease_skirt
        if @si <= 0
            @si = @skirts.count - 1
        else
            @si -= 1
        end   
        redirect_to root_path 
    end

Here is my home.html.erb
<h1> Main#home </h1>


<div>
  <div class='neckline'>
    <h3> <%= @necklines[@ni].style_name %> </h3>
    <div class='child inline-block-child'> <%= button_to "<", "/home/decrease_neck", method: :post %> </div>
    <div class='child inline-block-child'> <%= image_tag @necklines[@ni].image %> </div>
    <div class='child inline-block-child'> <%= button_to ">", "/home/increase_neck", method: :post %> </div>
  </div>
  <div class='skirt'>
    <div class='child inline-block-child'> <%= button_to "<", "/home/decrease_skirt", method: :post %> </div>
    <div class='child inline-block-child'> <%= image_tag @skirts[@si].image %> </div>
    <div class='child inline-block-child'> <%= button_to ">", "/home/increase_skirt", method: :post %> </div>
    <h3> <%= @skirts[@si].style_name %> </h3>
  </div>
</div>

Here is my routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/necklines', to: 'neckline#index'
  get "/necklines/:id", to: "neckline#show"
  get '/skirts', to: 'skirt#index'
  get '/skirts/:id', to: 'skirt#show'

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root "main#home"
end

I suspect the error is @ni and @si being assigned back to 0 each time I click the button, but am unsure on how to move forward.
Apologies for the messy code, stumbling my way through my first app!

You are just changing instance variables in the controller instance that was created to handle the current request. You do not save anything into the database or persist it otherwise. That means the next request is handled by another instance of the controller class that knows nothing about what happened in previous calls to the server. When you want your changes to persist then you need to store the state somehow, into the session, a cookie, or the database.

@spickermann Thank you, I didn't realise each action creates a new instance, but makes sense now that I know!
Would you recommend generating a new model to store the "NI" and "SI" values? What would then be the correct way to call them and save them?

I guess the easiest would be use a gem that adds pagination to our application, find some gems here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pagination. Usually, pagination is used to show 10 or 20 items per page and allows switching from one page to the other. But when you set per_page to just 1 then those tools would allow you to browser one article after the other with just one article on each page.

Instance variables won't carry through each request. I would add an auto-incremented field (maybe just use the ID for now) for the indices, which you pass through as a route parameter.
So in index you would have something like:
def index 
  @neckline = params[:neckline_idx] ? Neckline.find_by(id: params[:neckline_idx]) : Neckline.first
  @skirt = params[:skirt_idx] ? Skirt.find_by(id: params[:skirt_idx]) : Skirt.first
end

And your links to increment/decrement would look like:
# neckline increment/decrement links
link_to "<", root_path(neckline_idx: @neckline.id - 1, skirt_idx: params[:skirt_idx]) 
link_to ">", root_path(neckline_idx: @neckline.id + 1, skirt_idx: params[:skirt_idx])

# skirt increment/decrement links
link_to "<", root_path(skirt_idx: @skirt.id - 1, neckline_idx: params[:neckline_idx]) 
link_to ">", root_path(skirt_idx: @skirt.id + 1, neckline_idx: params[:neckline_idx])

You might want to eventually evolve the links to call a method like #next_id and #previous_id:
link_to "<", root_path(skirt_idx: @skirt.previous_id, neckline_idx: params[:neckline_idx]) 
link_to ">", root_path(skirt_idx: @skirt.next_id, neckline_idx: params[:neckline_idx])

So that it can handle gaps in your index if you allow destroying records:
def next_id
  self.where("id > ?", self.id).minimum(:id)
end

